# what are the ways that i can use in laravel 10 to change the engine in my sql by creating a new migration?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

i want to change the mysql innoDB engine to MyISAM using laravel migration i created the migration
that is names alter_products_engine that is suppose to change the table products but that is not happining

i made the table migration like below and i am expected the change happens but it dose not

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('products');
    }
};
```

and also the alter table migration

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::table('products',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->engine = 'MyISAM';
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::table('products',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->engine = 'MyISAM';
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Why have you tagged this Laravel 5, 8, and 10? Which is it?

Comment: Is that migration not working? I have never done this, but what issue are you having?

Comment: the main issue that the above code dose not reflect on MySQL it dose no change any thing on the database after running php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you to use directly an ALTER TABLE in your migration:

```
DB::statement('ALTER TABLE products ENGINE = MyISAM');
```

But we need more clarity about the behavior you are facing.

Comment: the main issue that the above code dose not reflect on MySQL it dose no change any thing on the database after running php artisan migrate

Comment: @MinaShaker are you making sure the current migration you are working on has been rolled back (doesn't exist as a record in the `migrations` table)